# LLVM Pass crashes when I try to add zext and call instructions

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have the following LLVM IR want to use printf to show the value of the %arrayidx.

```
%arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds float, float* %A, i64 %0
%1 = load float, float* %arrayidx, align 4
```

That is, the output should be:

```
%arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds float, float* %A, i64 %0
%2 = zext i64 %0 to i32
%call = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([12 x i8], [12 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32 %2)
%1 = load float, float* %arrayidx, align 4
```

So I have written the following LLVM pass:

```
Builder.SetInsertPoint(&BB);
Value *str = Builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr(StringRef("The index is %d\n"));

std::vector<Value*> args;
Value* idx = I->getOperand(1);
Value* idx32 = Builder.CreateIntCast(idx, Builder.getInt32Ty(), true);
args.push_back(str);
args.push_back(idx32);

Value* call_inst = Builder.CreateCall(ptf, args, "tmp");
```

But I got the following error:

```
opt: /llvm-6.0/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:255: typename llvm::cast_retty<X, Y*>::ret_type llvm::cast(Y*) [with X = llvm::Function; Y = llvm::Constant; typename llvm::cast_retty<X, Y*>::ret_type = llvm::Function*]: Assertion `isa<X>(Val) && "cast<Ty>() argument of incompatible type!"' failed.
```

Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: You replace the `zext` instruction with `trunc` for downcasting  an `i64` to  an `i32`. Use `Builder.CreateTrunc(idx, Builder.getInt32Ty())`

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I also found the bug is actually because of something else...   Now I am fixing a new bug...

Comment: @user9184672 Care to share what the bug was, for the sake of readers experiencing the same thing?